# How do I show the appartenence of a function to a space?

Tags: metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

How do I demonstrate that every $f(x)$ for which is valid $$\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|^2 (2+\sin^2(x)) < \infty $$ is in  $L^2 (-1,1)$ ?

I think the idea is that the quantity $(2+\sin^2(x))$ is limited, so if the whole integral is $< \infty$, must be $\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|^2 $ $< \infty$ , which is the definition of the function in the $L^2 (-1,1)$ space.

But how do I mathematically prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2 + \sin^2 x \in [1,3]$ we have:

$$\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2\,dx \le \int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2(2 + \sin^2x)\,dx \le 3\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2\,dx$$

So, one of the integrals is finite if and only if the other one is finite: $$\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2(2 + \sin^2x)\,dx < +\infty \iff \int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2\,dx < +\infty$$

Therefore:

$$\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2(2 + \sin^2x)\,dx < +\infty \iff f \in L^2(-1,1)$$